# hibernate property

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

can anyone explain on this 2 properties

Q1. hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer  ? what is the effect of setting to true and false

Q2. hibernate.c3p0.max_statements  . i read hibernate doc https://www.hibernate.org/214.html. it only mentioned default value is 0.  I am using oracle10g, and i set to 100. but i want to know how to find out what is the max database can support? also dose this property mean max length of sql statement can support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A1.** `false` will make Hibernate start faster since it does not try to build cglib-enhanced objects to access getter/setters, and use standard JDK reflection for access. It might have some negative impact on overall runtime performance, though. And the value `true` means just the opposite.

Refer to: https://www.hibernate.org/194.html

**A2.** It is the size of c3p0's PreparedStatement cache. Zero means statement caching is turned off.

As it seems from your comments, you are still not clear about the size of c3p0 for `PreparedStatement`. I think you should read on `PreparedStatement`, then you will be able to understand.

From the [docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html),

> A SQL statement is precompiled and
>   stored in a PreparedStatement object.
>   This object can then be used to
>   efficiently execute this statement
>   multiple times.

So, that means it caches the `PreparedStatement` objects. Underlying database doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: for A2, what is the max i can set? depend on database capability?

Comment: @cometta: No its not that. Its cache size for `PreparedStatement`. You need to understand `PreparedStatement`. BTW, c3p0 is a connection pool implementation, in case you are not aware of it.